# How to choose AuthenticationProviders based on request or an appropriate response on successful auth

Tags: spring-security

Is it currently possible to configure Spring Security that if a login request comes in, it will check first for the request then uses a specific list of AuthenticationProviders?

Example:

I have two type of login request, one uses email and mobile number. The request comes in with a client id. It checks first what the client id is and routes the request to a specific list of AuthenticationProviders.

Where should apply this logic? I tried extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter but it I could not choose which AuthenticationProviders to use as it gets the list from the AuthenticationManager.

Is it ok to have multiple AuthenticationManager instead?

---

**EDIT**

I tried chaoluo's comments here's what stopped me.

I can't check the contents of the Authentication object when

```
boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)
```

is invoked. I don't know if it's possible as I have limited knowledge on Reflection.

I am trying to achieve for each successful auth, the response will be different based on the client id.

I am not sure where to place my logic but here's a list of what I think should work but I still feel there is a better way.

1. Create two authentication managers - each manager will have it's own separate list of AuthenticationProviders so I can control which auth providers will be used based on client id
2. One ProcessingFilter, AuthenticationManager will try to authenticate, once successful, the AuthenticationSuccessHandler will check the client id on the Authentication object and generate a corresponding response based on the client id

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

Auth Request -> Try to authenticate -> Return response based on client id.

Comment: AuthenticationManager is based the `Authentication` to use different `AuthenticationProvider`, I think you can implement a processing filter that based the client id then create different sub class of `Authentication`, then implement two different `AuthenticationProvider` to support them.

Comment: @chaoluo Thanks! From what I understand, filter -> check client id -> use appropriate AuthProvider. Yeah that works but does that mean the filter won't use the AuthManager?

Comment: `AuthenticationProvider` `supports` method will test whether this provider can support the `Authentication`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Will try out your suggestion.

Comment: filter doesn't use `authProvider` directly, authProviders are a list in `ProviderManager` that implement `AuthenticationManager`.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll have to modify my AuthProviders to match what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I check the code, I think you should use two different `Authentication`, the test method just test the class, not the instance.